# SSL client certificate auth with ruby (sinatra)

Tags: ruby, ssl, sinatra, thin, client-certificates

How can I authorize an API in sinatra, so that only callers possessing a known client certificate (or one issued by a trusted CA) are allowed to call it?

Currently I am using the 'thin' webserver, but I am open to other options if that is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nginx` to take care of your client-certificate - here is a [blog post](http://blog.nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi) which shows how to set it up:

> ```
> server {
>     listen        443;
>     ssl on;
>     server_name example.com;
>
>     ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
>     ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
>     ssl_verify_client optional;
>
>     location / {
>         root           /var/www/example.com/html;
>         fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
>         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/lib/Request.class.php;
>         fastcgi_param  VERIFIED $ssl_client_verify;
>         fastcgi_param  DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
>         include        fastcgi_params;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> We specify our the server's certificate (server.crt) and private key
>   (server.key) We specify the CA cert that we used to sign our client
>   certificates (ca.crt) We set the ssl_verify_client to optional. This
>   tells nginx to attempt to verify to SSL certificate if provided. My
>   API allows both authenticated and unauthenticated requests, however if
>   you only want to allow authenticated requests, you can go ahead and
>   set this value to on.

You can use [`thin` with `nginx`](http://jordanhollinger.com/2011/12/19/deploying-with-thin), but I believe that using [`passenger` with `nginx`](http://javatech.org/2012/10/configuring-nginx-to-serve-ruby-sinatra-via-passenger/) is more popular in this case, and quite easy to deploy.

---

`ssl_verify_client optional` is explained [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule):

> ### ssl_verify_client
>
> ```
> Syntax:   ssl_verify_client on | off | optional | optional_no_ca
> Default:  off
> Context:   http | server
> Reference:    ssl_verify_client
> ```
>
> This directive enables the verification of the client identity.
>   Parameter 'optional' checks the client identity using its certificate
>   in case it was made available to the server.

Comment: Thank you!  This is indeed a step in the right direction.  Can you explain how the 'optional' verification works, or point me to documentation on that?  How would my Sinatra api method determine if the client has presented a valid certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Thin I don't think this is possible at the moment because peer verification appears to be broken. See https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/pull/203:

> "The get_peer_cert method of EM doesn't return anything unless the cert has been verified. The --ssl-verify option of thin actually doesn't do anything. These two behaviors combined mean that env['rack.peer_cert'], which was introduced in thin 1.2.8, always returns nil. Since --ssl-verify never actually caused a verification to happen, it is better to remove that option until a fully verification process is put in place. However, the peer_cert can be made available in --ssl mode by always "verifying" the cert, thereby providing the client supplied certificate, if there is one, available in env['rack.peer_cert']."

I believe Uri Agassi is partially correct by recommending passenger but I worry a nginx/thin combination introduces a security risk if you're expecting the cert to act as the authentication if thin is ever moved off the nginx server, thereby exposing your thin server. I think an embedded appserver solution is the way to go (a la passenger).

Comment: I am certainly open to other suggestions rather than thin.  I will look into passenger.  Do you have any data about puma in this regard?